# Set position of an EditText and TextView in a RelativeLayout programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout defined in main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

And add a TextView and EditText programatically in onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
setContentView(R.layout.main);

addContentView(customGlView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

addContentView(myTextView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
addContentView(myEditText, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

They both show up, but are overlapping in the top left corner. I've spend hours to figure out how to either position them just below each other, or one in the left corner of the screen and the other in the right corner. If I add them through the main.xml neither of them will show up. Can anyone give me a hint to the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

For a `RelativeLayout`, you need to specify the relative positions of your elements, using the `LayoutParams`:

```
myTextView.setId(1);
myEditText.setId(2);

addContentView(myTextView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, myTextView.getId());
addContentView(myEditText, params);
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. I've assigned IDs to both views via setId() as in Raoul Georges answer, but they are still drawn on top of each other.

Comment: Hmm, weird. Are you sure you're using distinct LayoutParams variables? If you reuse the same you will get unpredictable results

Comment: Yes, I'm using one distinct LayoutParams for each one. One with BELOW and the other with ABOVE.

Comment: You don't need to specify both: start placing your first view, and then indicate the relative position of the second one to the first one - I edited my answer to show exactly what you need to do, and it should work (not tested, I'm at work)

Comment: @Guillaume: hi,i have tried your code but it gives me error at param.addRule(...).It seems that the method is not for LayoutParams and it is for RelativeLayout.LayoutParams only.Are you sure for this line of code?

Comment: Ah! Maybe you're using the wrong LayoutParams then! RelativeLayout.LayoutParams is the one you should use! Check your imports (edited my answer)

Comment: Also doesn't work, the views still overlap :(. I already used RelativeLayout.LayoutParams before, because your previous version gave me the same error as Hiral described.

Comment: Oh yes...it resolved the error.thanks.But still it is not giving desired results.it is overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

Add a rule to your LayoutParams which will set one textview below the other..

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 

TextView tv1 = new TextView(this); 
tv1.setId(1); 
tv1.setText("myTextView"); 

params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv1.getId()); 
TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve this with RelativeLayout, but using [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) does exactly what you want to do.

```
addView(myEditText);
```

Or you can use [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int)) to add them to any position you want. For example, you can first add myEditText and then add myTextView above myEditText:

```
addView(myEditText);
addView(myTextView, 0);
```