# Change TextView's position dynamically using java in RelativeLayout android

Tags: java, android, layout, android-relativelayout

i have RelativeLayout, and there is a textview in the RelativeLayout, i am getting position from server like ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, based on that value i want to change position of textview...

My xml file is....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/share_text"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/share_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i have got knowledge from [Set position of an EditText and TextView in a RelativeLayout programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094421/set-position-of-an-edittext-and-textview-in-a-relativelayout-programatically) to chage the position but couldn't help me

can any body help me how to change position of textview dynamically...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new 
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 

params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
yourTextview.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

Comment: but if i want to put like params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM|RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE); then it is not working

Comment: just set one parameter at a time

Comment: oh then it is not possible to put two paramater at a time?

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)yourView.getLayoutParams()).alignParentTop =
     serverResponse.equals("ALIGN_PARENT_TOP");
```

?

Of course you have to do some parsing of your server response, etc...